# How to store every items in localstorage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am new to learning javascript. I am saving items in **localstorage** and it saves successfully. I can see the result in the **console** also but the problem is that an old item gets replaced with a new item. I want to save each of the items in localstorage as an add-to-cart.

```
function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var Title, Price, Image
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName("name-of-product")[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('product-price')[0].innerText
    var image = shopItem.getElementsByClassName("hover-img")[0].src

    let itemsList = {
        Title: title,
        Price: price,
        Image: image,
    }    
    let cartItems = {
        [itemsList.Title]: itemsList
    }
    localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
    cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    console.log("This is without json", cartItems);
}
```

Comment: You could store an array. You'll have to load/parse it, append, then stringify/set it.

Comment: localStorage is a simple key/value storage system - the key `productsInCart` will only have the _latest_ value you set to it (which you'd probably want to set as an array as nlta suggests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[localStorage.setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) will add that key to the localstorage of the browser, or oerwites that key's value if it already exists.

So your old data will be overwritten once you executes `localStorage.setItem`

What you have to do is, you have to extract the current value in local storage using [localStorage.getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), add the new value to that extracted value and update the local storage with the new value that consist of old and new data.

So your code will be something like below

```
function addToCartClicked(event) {
    var Title, Price, Image
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName("name-of-product")[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('product-price')[0].innerText
    var image = shopItem.getElementsByClassName("hover-img")[0].src

    let itemsList = {
        Title: title,
        Price: price,
        Image: image,
    }
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
    cartItems = cartItems ? JSON.parse(cartItems) : {};
    cartItems[itemsList.Title] = itemsList;
    localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
    cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    console.log("This is without json", cartItems);
}
```